# Rails view isn't passing the data to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

So the method from the mailer works. I have tried calling it from the console. The issue is that the content variable appears to be empty. So when I  call ContactMailer.contact_email from the console [heroku] it works. I am not sure why =c

I have also tried doing params[:post][:email] .. to no avail :C

## controller

```
  def contact_email #now how to pass email and content
    email = params[:email]
    content = params[:content]
    ContactMailer.contact_email(email, content).deliver
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
  end
```

## view

```
   <%= form_tag(contact_email_path) do %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Email Address' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <%= label_tag 'content', 'Content' %>
         <%= text_area_tag 'content', nil, class: 'form-control', rows: 4, placeholder: 'Content' %>
       </div>
      <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
    <% end %>
```

## route

```
match '/contact_email', to: 'pages#contact_email', via: 'post'
```

## heroku log

```
2014-04-23T22:25:25.169161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/contact_email host=hs-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=6f3753a7-10a0-4354-86b0-81893afefc52 fwd="108.23.126.184" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=2276ms status=302 bytes=659
2014-04-23T22:25:25.430981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/contact host=hs-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=1c5081eb-eb5d-48eb-9d58-8c699d12f6a3 fwd="108.23.126.184" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=9356
```

Comment: Please post relevant `log/development.log`

Comment: I just added the heroku log! what happens is the email is sent but the variables are empty!

Comment: That's whole log or you skipped params line? That's what I wanted to see actually.

Comment: Okay. This is weird. I looked at the logs and the email looked how it was supposed to look after sending it on localhost. aah

Comment: Some weird configuration? Are you using strong_params, no errors there?

Comment: Oh. Okay...so the issue was resolved when I added a .text.erb email view, even though we use gmail which uses the .html.erb email with no problems..... So it works now! and I feel silly @__@

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose heroku requires a .text.erb email view even if the email client being sent to isn't using it...